# LinkName appears differently for different recipients

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, sql

In our Journey, we are setting an `ALIAS` using AMPscript and are using a SQL to find clickers on that specific URL to create a Target DE for a follow-up/confirmation email.

**But there are different values for different customers -- any idea why this is happening?**

The result was our confirmation email only deployed to a handful of recipients when it should have went to 100s.  Below is a screenshot of the results from the **_Click** table.

[image: Different Link Names]

Comment: I have had this happen to me in the past. Was always when trying to use dynamic alias set from AMPScript. I have a feeling there is a limit on the number of different alias you can have for a particular job.

Answer (score 1):

this is a known platform limitation and rather annoying. The platform stops evaluating the dynamic aliases at 100 unique names.
The behavior is described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dynamicLinkNames.htm).

One possible workaround is a grouping of possible link names in your ampscript or data extension to reduce the number of generated unique link names. If that works for you depends on your reporting needs but I guess it's still a better deal than the current situation.

Comment: I just rechecked your screenshot and had a bit of an idea. The approach would be based on a send logging data extension where you can write the subscriber specific merchant id. With some query magic you can then pull together the clicks for specific merchants. The approach might get bungled when you refer multiple merchants in one email, however.